# Stop an application from being terminated, without entering the correct password? c#

Tags: c#, winapi

I was just wondering is there anyway to stop application being terminated at all without a password being entered. Is it even possible? I've seen net nanny type applications do it so that the user is unable to terminate it in the Task Manager without putting a password in.

can anyone help me??

thanks MAtt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to stop a process from being terminated. To paraphrase Raymond Chen: what would happen if you could do that? All you can (and should) do is restrict *which users* can terminate the process.

That is: if (for example) you run your process as a Windows service, then only administrators will be able to stop it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is running as a limited user (not an administrator), this is fairly easy to do; you need to remove all rights from the process' ACL.

If the user is an administrator, there are more dangerous options.

Comment: and the dangerous options are?