# Protect process from Terminate By Process Explorer or Other Process Managers

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I wrote the program that I need a code that prevents the closure through the application from process managers (e.g Process Explorer)

My program is not malicious Software and is an application that is monitoring the Internet connection.

Thanks.

Comment: How many processes do you know of which cannot be stopped? You would do better to find out why your users are stopping your program, and to give them fewer reasons to stop it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Measures to prevent from closing a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649468/measures-to-prevent-from-closing-a-program)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop an application from being terminated, without entering the correct password? c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946735/stop-an-application-from-being-terminated-without-entering-the-correct-password)

Answer (score 0):

Name your application the same as a critical windows service process and run it from system32.  You can even have your application change the name of the executable each time it runs so it can be hard to know which process to kill.  TrendMicro does this with their virus scanner.

Additionally, you can run another application alongside yours which monitors if your application is running.  If it isn't then restart it.   Or instead of another application, use a scheduled task that runs once every minute or five minutes with security restrictions so other users can't remove your scheduled task.

That said, I totally disagree with what you're doing.  But assuming it's your employees you're monitoring, it is your right.